# How to compare both date and time in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, compare

I have an sql query where I want to compare BOTH the date and time because I am simulating both date and time. But it seems to be comparing the date part only. Here's the stored procedure:

```
Create PROCEDURE GPSTest_GPSEvent_DeleteOneUnit  (@dateFrom DateTime, @dateTo DateTime, @gpsunit int)
AS
BEGIN
Delete from GPSEvent where GPSUnitID = @gpsunit and  GPSEventDateTime between @dateFrom and @dateTo
return @@ROWCOUNT;
END
GO
```

I don't know if anyone has any idea why it's comparing the date part only?

Comment: What is the format of `GPSEventDateTime` and the two in parameters?

Comment: @sagi They are both datetime

Comment: Some sample data, an example call to the stored procedure and then what you *expect* the table to look like afterwards would assist us greatly. At a guess though, by "it seems to be comparing the date part only" I think you're referring to the fact that when you pass `@dateTo` as '20160520', you're somehow expecting that to match items that happen *during* the 20th, despite the fact that I doubt, if you passed '2016-05-20T15:00:00', you wouldn't expect it (I assume) to match values on the 20th that happen after 3pm.

Comment: Are you sure that the GPSEventDateTime column and parameters has the time part? 
According to the MSDN: When the time part is unspecified, it defaults to 12:00 A.M.

Comment: This should work fine. By the way have in mind that `checkDate between startDate and endDate` is the same as `checkDate>=startDate and checkDate<=endDate`. In most cases this is not what the developer wants.